# Converting strings to methods that output the string

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
options: {
  'Signature': "[Customer First Name] [Customer Last Name]"
  'First Name': "[Customer First Name]"
  'Last Name': "[Customer Last Name]"
}
```

And I need to convert it so that the values become functions that use that value like this:

```
options: {
  'Signature': function(){ this.insertHTML('[Customer First Name][Customer Last Name]'); }
  'First Name': function(){ this.insertHTML('[Customer First Name]'); }
  'Last Name': function(){ this.insertHTML('[Customer Last Name]'); }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this. So as an example I want to be able to do something like:

```
var newOptions = functionify(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one potential solution. Iterate over the keys of `options` and build up a new object:

```
var newOptions = Object.keys(options).reduce(function ( obj, option ) {
  obj[ option ] = function () {
    this.insertHTML(options[ option ]);
  };
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Note that `this` inside those functions is unlikely to refer to what you expect it to, unless you're invoking those functions with some other explicit context (e.g. via `call` or `apply`).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, it's possible to create functions which *return functions*.

For example:

```
function functionify(str) {
  return function() {
    return str; // Or whatever you want in your function body.
  };
}
```

So, by calling `functionify` and passing some string to it, you'll get in return a function which returns that string:

```
var fun = functionify('Hello, World!'); // fun is now a function

fun(); // returns "Hello, World!"
```

This can be applied to keys and values of an object in any of several ways (depending on your preference; a for-in loop, `Object.keys` to name a couple).

Another example:

```
obj['key'] = functionify(obj['key']);
obj['key']();
```